# Combine states and validators - flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, validation, states

I'm making a online shop for my schoolproject and I have a problem I can't solve.

Now I made form for the users to fill in and I have added some validators to check if the users filled in the correct information. After the user filled in the form they can click the submitbutton to continue.

I'm also working with states so when I push the submitbutton I will go to the next page.

now my problem is: Even if the user doesnt fill in the form and he clicks on "submit" he still goes to the next page. The validation works but it doesnt stop the user for continueing.

this is my validation code

```
<mx:EmailValidator id="emailValidator"
                       source="{email}"
                       property="text"
                       triggerEvent="change"/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="nameValidator"
                        source="{Name}"
                        property="text"
                        requiredFieldError="Put in a name"
                        triggerEvent="change"/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="SurnameValidator"
                        source="{Surname}"
                        property="change"
                        requiredFieldError="Put in a surname"
                        triggerEvent="click"/>
    <s:NumberValidator id="PostcodeValidator"
                       source="{Postcode}"
                       property="text"
                       requiredFieldError="Put in a zipcode"
                       triggerEvent="change"/>
```

Now button code

```
<s:Button label="submit"
              id="submitButton"
              click="currentState='Shoppingstate'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind enabled property of submitButton to validators' states

Comment: My intuition tells me this won't work; as what would prevent someone from clicking "Submit" without entering any data?  The default state--I suspect--would be active.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from setting enabled=false as the default.

Answer (score -1):

I'd perform a check on every field.  First change the submit button click event handler to a formal method:

```
<s:Button label="submit"
              id="submitButton"
              click="onSubmit(event)"/>
```

Then check the validation approach in the method:

```
protected function onSubmit(event:Event):void{
 if((email.errorString == '') && (Name.errorString == '') && (Surname.errorString == '') (Postcode == '')){
 currentState='Shoppingstate'
}
}
```